# How to convert an image into tattoo?

Tags: android, image

Am working the app for tattoolater in that i required to convert an image(which is taken from camera or selected from gallery)into tattoo...

my requirement is like the following

[image]
   I found a sample code from github 
`https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter/tree/master/Android/project`

its for imagefiltering..

i dont know is this correct process to convert an image to tattoo or not

if anybody know for this tattoo in android please suggest me i googled a lot

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Useless observation : the image is from an iphone?

Comment: [Edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a difference filter:

1) you calc the horizontal difference (here you'll have vertical segments)

2) you calc the vertical difference (here, horizontal segments)

3) you OR the two maps, finding the outlines

4) recreate a Bitmap object, if you wish to do so

something like (EDITED):

```
int[] pixels;
int width = yourbitmap.getWidth();
int height = yourbitmap.getHeight();
yourbitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

// transform grayscale
int[] image = new int[width*height];
for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
    {
        int pixel = image[y*width + x];
        image[y*width + x] = (Color.red(pixel) + Color.green(pixel) + Color.blue(pixel))/3;
    }

// calculate diff_x (vertical segments)
int[] dx = new int[width*height];

for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
        dx[y*width + x] = (x==0 || y== 0 ? 0 : Math.abs(image[y*width + x] - image[y*width + x-1]));

// calculate diff_y (horizontal segments)
int[] dy = new int[width*height];

for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
        dy[y*width + x] = (x==0 || y== 0 ? 0 : Math.abs(image[y*width+x] - image[(y-1)*width+x])); 


// when the color intensity is higher than THRESHOLD, accept segment
// you'll want a slider to change THRESHOLD values
bool[] result = new bool[width*height];
const int THRESHOLD = 60; // adjust this value

for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
        result[y*width + x] = (dx[y*width + x] > THRESHOLD || dy[y*width + x] > THRESHOLD);

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
               result.setPixel(x, y, result[y*width+x]? Color.Black : Color.White);
```

Comment: how to calculate horizontal difference and vertical difference for bitmap

Comment: the posted code should calculate both the differences and the final OR, the only thing missing is the conversion bitmap->byte[][]matrix.  I don't know much of android, but i think that Bitmap.getPixels(...) should do the trick

Comment: sorry,its not working in android the bitmap is converting to byte[]matrix only and its not converting to byte[][]matrix and also here the image.x and image.y are not recognized...could u give the clear explonation

Comment: code edited, should be easier to implement

Comment: Then how set finally to image the converted bitmap...you are storing the value in bool know it is not recognized in bitmap.setpixels() method..

Comment: create a bitmap object and setpixel black where the bool is true and white where is false, see edited code

Comment: run time error at this line (IllegalState Exeption)  bm.setPixel(x, y, result[y*width+x]? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);

Comment: Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); maybe? I'm sorry I have very little experience of android/java... I can't help much more with point #4

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggetion (without much knowledge on android....) i tried with the code but it converts white color image...not my requirement

Comment: working good small mistake in that code...change the int pixel = image[y*width + x]; to int pixel = pixels[y*width + x]; Thank you @Exceptyon

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 public static Bitmap ConvertToBlackAndWhite(Bitmap sampleBitmap) {
        ColorMatrix bwMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
        bwMatrix.setSaturation(0);
        final ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                bwMatrix);
        Bitmap rBitmap = sampleBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(rBitmap);
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(rBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        return doBlackWhiteImage(rBitmap);
    }

public static BlackWhiteImage doBlackWhiteImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        int[] allpixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth()];
        myBitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < myBitmap.getHeight() * myBitmap.getWidth(); i++) {
            if (allpixels[i] == Color.BLACK)
                // do something
            else if (allpixels[i] == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                // do something
            else if (allpixels[i] == Color.WHITE)
                // do something
            else {
                allpixels[i] = Color.WHITE;
            }
        }
        myBitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
        return myBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: i tried with ur code it shows the white image after passed my bitmap to ConvertToBlackAndWhite() this method

Comment: In the doBlackWhiteImage() you are checking the pixel with white,transparent,black and else default color white is assigning(how to check the remaining colors),so  i think thats the problem...please could you solve this