# How to convert bitmap background to transparent without disturbing the actual image?

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing

I used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610609/how-to-convert-an-image-into-tattoo) to convert actual image to the following

[image: converted image]

upto this it's good and working fine..but my problem is the background of this image is white and how to convert to transparent without disturbing the foreground image..

for this I used the code

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(results);
c.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
c.drawBitmap(results, 0, 0, null);
```

but it's not converting the background to transparent and also I used setAlpha(100) function it's also not working..

Comment: I'd say manually. The reason is, you can't programmatically specify what areas of your image is background, and what's foreground, especially if your foreground color (face) equals to background color (wall).

Comment: no those are not equal..please see the code i used in the hyperlink

Comment: Again I'd say manually, you are basically asking for foreground/background detection algorithm, which IMHO is not formalizable as is.

Comment: is it possible or not ?

Comment: can't you just replace white color with transparent color by converting your image into an array of colors?

Comment: Even Photoshop can't do what you want automatically. E.g. the black bars in the background are not distinguishable from the black shirt - it's all just dark pixels for a computer. And computers don't know the concept of a shirt or the shape of human body so they don't know which areas belong to which. Also the perception of depth in the image is added by your brain. If you want to remove backgrounds automatically you need special images like used in TV: uniform green or blue backgrounds since replacing a certain color is possible.

Comment: I second @Waqas' suggestion, if I understand correctly, you're not asking for a foreground/background detection algorithm (that was done in the referenced algorithm), but to simply convert white pixels to transparent. The simplest way to do this is to iterate through each pixel and if it is white, make it transparent.

Comment: yes i already did ....this thought applied yesterday after posted the question...anyway thank you @Noremac